# Is there a Python function that removes characters (with a digit) from a string?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, heatmap

I am working on a project about gentrification. My teammates pulled data from the census and cleaned it to get the values we need. The issue is, the zip code values won't print 0's (i.e. "2322" when it should be "02322"). We managed to find the tact value that prints the full zip code with the tact codes("ZCTA5 02322"). I want to remove "ZCTA5" to get the zip code alone.

I've tried the below code but it only gets rid of the "ZCTA" instead of "ZCTA5" (i.e. "502322"). I'm also concerned that if I manage to remove the 5 with the characters, it will remove all 5's in the zip codes as well.

From there I will be pulling from pgeocode to access the respective lat & lng values to create the heatmap. Please help?

I've tried the .replace(), .translate(), functions. Replace still prints the zip codes with 5. Translate gets an attribute error.

## Sample data

```
Zipcode | Name        | Change_In_Value | Change_In_Income | Change_In_Degree | Change_In_Rent
2322    | ZCTA5 02322 | -0.050242       | -0.010953        |  0.528509        | -0.013263
2324    | ZCTA5 02324 |  0.012279       | -0.022949        | -0.040456        |  0.210664
2330    | ZCTA5 02330 |  0.020438       |  0.087415        | -0.095076        | -0.147382
2332    | ZCTA5 02332 |  0.035024       |  0.054745        |  0.044315        |  1.273772
2333    | ZCTA5 02333 | -0.012588       |  0.079819        |  0.182517        |  0.156093
```

---

## Translate

```
zipcode = []

test2 = gent_df['Name'] = gent_df['Name'].astype(str).translate({ord('ZCTA5'): None}).astype(int)

zipcode.append(test2)

test2.head()
```

---

---

## Replace

```
zipcode = []

test2 = gent_df['Name'] = gent_df['Name'].astype(str).replace(r'\D', '').astype(int)

zipcode.append(test2)

test2.head()
```

---

## Replace

Expected:

```
24093
26039
34785
38944
29826
```

Actual:

```
524093
526039
534785
538944
529826
```

## Translate

Expected:

```
24093
26039
34785
38944
29826
```

Actual:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-0e5ff4660e45> in <module>
      3 zipcode = []
      4 
----> 5 test2 = gent_df['Name'] = gent_df['Name'].astype(str).translate({ord('ZCTA5'): None}).astype(int)
      6 # zipcode.append(test2)
      7 test2.head()

~\Anaconda3\envs\MyPyEnv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5178             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5179                 return self[name]
-> 5180             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5181 
   5182     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

Comment: A lot of this can likely be avoided from the beginning. ZIP codes look numeric, so pandas will parse them as such. You should instead specify `dtype={'Zipcode': object}` when you parse the file and the zeros will remain in the 5 digit zip code.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using pandas so you should be able to use the .lstrip() method. I tried this on a sample df and it worked for me:

`gent_df.Name = gent_df.Name.str.lstrip(to_strip='ZCTA5')`

Here is a link to the library page for `.strip()`, `.lstrip()`, and `.rstrip()`

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks shaun-ogrady! quick question—will the output come out as an integer or can I add .astype(int) to convert? actually i’ll run a .dtypes test first..

Comment: Unfortunately, the current code produces string output. If you wrap it as an integer, python drops the leading zero. Typically, numerical data such as Integer and Double have specific relational properties. For example 101 is more than 100 and 11 is the same distance from 10 as 101 is from 100. However, with zip codes, there is no such relationship. For example, one cannot say that the zip code '02322' is greater than the zip code '02321' because postal codes are generated non-numerically.  Here is a great post on datatypes: https://towardsdatascience.com/data-types-in-statistics-347e152e8bee

Comment: Stings can still be sorted, so a comparison exists. ZIP codes should be kept as objects to keep the leading zero. If space is a concern then make them a category, given there are a finite and small set of them.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. I can think of 2 off the top of my head.

If you want to keep the last 5 characters of the zipcode string, regardless of whether they are digits or not:

```
gent_df['Name'] = gent_df['Name'].str[-5:]
```

If want to get the last 5 digits of the zipcode string:

```
gent_df['Name'] = gent_df['Name'].str.extract(r'(\d{5})$')[0]
```

Include some sample data for more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks Code Different, I added the DataFrame I'm working with.

Comment: See my edited answer. I don't know why you made `zipcode` a separate Python list

Comment: The list part, from what I understand, is what I need to create a heatmap in the end. I’ll send the output (or error) of what I mean.